# Delphi XE4 FireMonkey TMemo Transparent? (iOS)

Tags: ios, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4, tmemo

Is there any way to make the TMemo transparent in Delphi/iOS/FireMonkey?

I don't see any way to edit styles myself when selecting + right-clicking the memo control...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing memo's background on applying style event.

```
procedure TForm1.Memo1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  BckObject: TFmxObject;
begin
  BckObject := Memo1.FindStyleResource('background');
  if Assigned(BckObject) and (BckObject is TSubImage) then
  begin
    TSubImage(BckObject).Source := nil;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the style of the control you want to display transparent as you want. Unfortunately Embarcadero does not provide a fully functional example, only some information on the [Customizing FireMonkey Applications with Styles](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Customizing_FireMonkey_Applications_with_Styles) topic

Comment: I see this: "To see the style definitions in the FireMonkey Style Designer:

    Drop a control on a form in the Form Designer.
    Right-click the control and choose Edit Default Style" ... **but** I don't have any option called **Edit Default Style** which is rather odd. Does this work for you? Is my XE4/Pro + mobile addon installation messed up somehow?

Comment: @tom, this menu items have been deliberately removed when developing iOS apps. Getting to the built in styles for iOS is very complex.

Comment: @MikeSutton, actually it was removed because there was a serious bug that still hasn't been resolved. There is no reason to remove this otherwise and will eventually be reintroduced.

Comment: Any alternative way of getting a transparent TMemo then? :)

Comment: @Tom  Just as an idea. Have you tried removing background on applying style event? `procedure TForm1.Memo1ApplyStyleLookup(Sender: TObject);
var
  BckObject: TFmxObject;
begin
  BckObject := Memo1.FindStyleResource('background');
  if Assigned(BckObject) and (BckObject is TSubImage) then
  begin
    TSubImage(BckObject).Source := nil;
  end;
end;`

Comment: @slotomo That works! Make it answer and I will give bounty :)