# How to change Edit control background color in FireMonkey?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I just can't find a way of changing background color of Edit control in my mobile FireMonkey application.

Comment: Please supply Delphi version. FMX is very fluid between versions. You'll need to learn about FMX styles. A web search should reveal what you need.

Comment: Thats Embarcadero® Delphi® XE4 Version 18.0.4905.60485

Comment: I've edited the question to add that as a tag. That's the way to do it, for future reference.

Comment: I have version in the title.

Comment: @EdijsKolesnikovičs StackOverflow works quite well when you put your Delphi version in the tags. It tends to clutter space when you put it in the title.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. My mistake. Anyway, it is better in the tags, FWIW.

Comment: Via design time you can replace the style image used for the background, this however depends on the platform. At Runtime you could solve this by manipulating the bitmap of the background TSubImage of the style.

Answer (score 7):

I dont know about FMX for mobile, but in FMX for Mac/Win you should do following steps:

1. Right click on TEdit and select Edit Custom Style
2. In Structure window, expand **editstyle** (TLayout)
3. Put a TRectangle on **content** (TRectangle becomes child of content)
4. Change Rectangle.HitTest to False
5. Change Rectangle.Align to alClient
6. Change Rectangle.Fill.Color to a custom color
7. Change Rectangle.Stroke.Kind to bkNone
8. Apply and Close

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've removed my down vote and voted up, you were correct, this does seem to work. However the OP will get stuck at the first instruction due to there not being any Edit Custom Style popup menu choice in Firemonkey mobile(xe4).

Comment: Indeed, I have no 'Edit Custom Style' in XE4.

Comment: @EdijsKolesnikovičs Instead of "Edit Custom Style" you can achive same result if you add rectangle on Edit ApplyStyleLookup event in runtime. Check this similar [question:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653139/delphi-xe4-firemonkey-tmemo-transparent-ios/17764884#17764884)